# How do I spell check table in office 365?

Tags: microsoft-office, office365

I'm typing a minutes of meeting and the spell check doesn't recognized spelling error inside the table. I'm using office 365, word 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Mine does spell check in tables and I haven't made any changes to the default configuration as far as I am aware. Anyway, try this.

Select All - Ctrl + A

Review Tab > Language > Set Proofing Language

Make sure the box next to "Do not check spelling or grammar" is unticked.